# Download Internet Explorer 6 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-6

I know Internet Explorer 6 was built for XP but is their a copy that I can download on my Windows 7 machine for debugging purposes?  Internet Explorer 9 has an excellent developer console but the browsing modes only include 7-9.  It would be great if there was an Internet Explorer 9 build with 6 as a browsing option but there isn't as far as I can tell.  Someone suggested I run Windows XP in VirtualBox, but I'd rather just install it in Windows 7 if possible.

Comment: Try http://www.browsium.com/unibrows/ (I'm not affiliated). See also: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage and  http://apcmag.com/how_to_install_ie6_on_vista.htm

Comment: [Use Internet Explorer 6 and 7 in Virtual Box](http://superuser.com/q/76215)

Answer (score 9):

The recommended way to test using IE 6 on a Windows 7 PC is to run a Windows XP virtual machine with IE 6. You can download this (Windows_XP_IE6.exe) for free from Microsoft at: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 1):

Installing IE 6 cannot be done in Windows 7 Directly and if there were some hack to do so, I wouldn't recommend relying on it to present appropriately.

While you can use Virtual Box, VMWare, or some other virtualization product, the best option from a cost perspective is almost certainly to use XP Mode which is a pre-built XP Virtual Machine provided by Microsoft.  XP Mode requires you have Windows 7 Pro, Enterprise, or Ultimate.  If you don't have Windows 7 Pro, upgrading to Pro is the cheapest way of doing this - using the Windows Anytime Upgrade, it costs about $90 to go to Pro. Otherwise, you'd have to purchase a full retail copy of Windows 7 (or find an old full retail copy of XP) if you don't have one lying around.  Such a copy would likely cost you close to $300.

Comment: You could simply use XP Mode inside VirtualBox if you are running an unsupported version of Windows.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff - What are you talking about? The only unsupported versions of Windows 7 I'm aware of are pirated versions.

Comment: According to Microsoft's website, the only 'supported' versions are Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate. Try going to [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) and selecting a different Windows version.

Comment: For XP Mode?  It's not just unsupported - it's a license violation if you somehow manage to get XP Mode into Home Premium or Starter.  When offering solutions I try to both phrase and discuss things that are only available technically and legally.